# Mysql MATCH AGAINST and IN

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to search some data in my database. But main problem is that i search with match against:

```
...MATCH(description) AGAINST ("*52*" in boolean mode)
```

But on one iteration (or more, but with one query) i must search not only for 52, but for `50,51,52,...,59`  as before...
But is it real to do? 
Also i do it with RoR:

```
 @accums = Accumulator.find(:all, :conditions => ["MATCH(description) AGAINST (? in boolean mode)", size])
```

Or i will need to do iterator on rails, and search for all of them iteration by iteration?

Comment: This is confusingly worded.  Can you post sample data?  Are you searching for multiple needles in this haystack?  Could you describe the needles and the haystack a little better?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @AllInOne read my question, all is there... i must search not only for 52, but for `50,51,52,...,59`  as before...  For example i must search not only for 52, but for 52, 53 etc (i can be look like sql IN, but for match against)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say:

```
 MATCH(description) AGAINST ("*52*" in boolean mode)
```

Against a row where 'description' is:

```
34,520,1000,9000
```

or

```
34,452,1000,9000
```

or

```
34,4525,1000,9000
```

You will get a match. Is that your desired result?

I am guessing not.

I think what you want is:

```
MATCH(description) AGAINST ("52" in boolean mode)
```

And to handle multiple matches you would want:

```
MATCH(description) AGAINST ("51 52 53" in boolean mode)
```

Examples:

```
34,520,1000,9000
// no match

34,452,1000,9000
// no match

34,52,1000,9000
// match

34,53,1000,9000
// match

34,52,53,9000
// match
```

Untested.